# "Provided countryId does not exist" Error 500

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

Magento: 2.4.3 
Delivery method: In-Store Delivery
Stage: "Select Store" dialog in the checkout.

corresponding line in the log:

> [2022-05-06 11:50:34] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-62750b8a1bf61; Message: Provided countryId does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-62750b8a1bf61; Message: Provided countryId does not exist. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): Provided countryId does not exist. at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/Country/Postcode/Validator.php:39)"} []

url:

> /rest/default/V1/inventory/in-store-pickup/pickup-locations?

if the GET parameter **searchRequest%5Barea%5D%5BsearchTerm%5D** is set and equals test%3AIE , then there is the error 500; if the parameter equals test%3AUS or test%3ADE there is no error and reply is fine - provides pickup location.

IE is country code of Ireland

Comment: Please check that the shipping method which you uses allow that country..

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Magento 2.4 "In-Store Delivery" method in Stores>Configuration>Delivery Methods, seems not to have allowed countries selection.

Comment: did you find solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a module, and adding a **zip_codes.xml** file to etc folder inside the module folder (example: app\code\test_dev\test_module_name\etc\zip_codes.xml) with the applicable contents for IE (Ireland) fixed the Error 500.
As I understand, if default zip_codes.xml has no entry for your country and you get the message ("Provided countryId does not exist") and Error 500 in the log - you may need to create a module as above.